# Error in VIM indent

Tags: vim

When I indent in **VIM** with `==`, I get the following error:

> /bin/bash: indent: command not found 
>   :.!indent shell returned 127.

When I tried to indent a block of code with `=i{`, nothing is indented, and nothing is changed, and no error is through.

What is wrong with my VIM? I am using Fedora's Gnome 3.4.2 and my vim is 7.3.682

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which language or file type you were editing, and that can matter.  It also matters what's in your `~/.vimrc` (and possibly system-wide vimrc).  However, I can offer one bit of advice. Try clearing your 'equalprg' option:

```
:set equalprg=
```

Then run your `=` indent motion again.  If that works, you will want to find out what is setting your 'equalprg' option for you so you can stop it from happening.  To do this, restart vim and type (with the question mark as part of the command):

```
:verbose set equalprg?
```

Vim has very powerful indent features, and usually it is enough to have this line in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:filetype indent on
```

This enables per-filetype indent plugins, which generally sets up the necessary indent options (there are a few) for you based on the current language or filetype.  You may want to look at:

```
:help :filetype
:help 'equalprg'
```

Comment: i tried ':set equalprg=' and it gave me the exact same error. I'm new to VIM and didn't know the command are different for different language. I'm just using it as a text editor of plain text to practice using VIM

Comment: Try the `:filetype indent on` command and reload the file (`:edit`) then see if the `=` motion command works.

Comment: where to reload the file name (:edit)? is that a hidden file?

Comment: Just typing "`:edit`" and pressing enter causes Vim to reload the current file.

Answer (score 0):

You may install the required package first with command
Debian:

```
apt install indent
```

CentOS:

```
yum install indent
```

After that you may select a code with "Shift+v" and indent selected with "=". Or just type "gg=G" to indent all lines.